# How do I convert lowercase and underscores to proper case and spaces in ES6/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I convert strings with underscores into spaces and converting it to proper case?

**CODE**

```
 const string = sample_orders

 console.log(string.replace(/_/g, ' '))
```

**Expected Output**

```
Sample Orders
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.replace` replace only the first occurrence of the target input. In order to replace all the occurrences, use `.replaceAll`.

```
 var string = 'sample_orders'

 string = string.replaceAll('_', ' ')
```

Further converting it to the proper case could be accomplished through `regEx`

```
string = string.replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, firstCharOfWord => firstCharOfWord.toUpperCase());
```

Where:

**^\w** : First char of the string

**|** : or

**\s\w** : First char after whitespace

**g** : global scope(Match all occurrences)

The second argument is a function that accepts the first character of each word computed using the regular expression and converts it to an upper case.
Binding the above logic into a function:

```
function formatString(string){
 
 return string.replaceAll('_', ' ').replaceAll(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, firstCharOfWord => firstCharOfWord.toUpperCase());

}

let formattedString = formatString('sample_orders')
console.log(formattedString) //Sample Orders
```

**Caveat**: You might encounter an error saying `.replaceAll` is not a function if you are running on an older browser or runtime environment.
The `.replaceAll` method was added in ES2021/ES12. The best workaround to run such functionalities on older versions of JS is to provide native support to older versions that do not support newly added methods or features ( `.replaceAll`) in this case.

```
function formatString(string){

 return string.replace(/_/g, ' ').replace(/(^\w|\s\w)/g, firstCharOfWord => firstCharOfWord.toUpperCase());

}
let formattedString = formatString('sample_orders')
console.log(formattedString) //Sample Orders
```

Note that we're using the `replace` method with regular expressions on a global scope. This could also be used at instances where the strings might not contain underscores.

Comment: Can you put it into one single function?

Comment: Have added, please check.

Comment: Why don't you use `replaceAll` in both cases? There is also no need for reassigning to the variable, you can chain the function calls: `return string.replaceAll(...).replaceAll(...);`.

Comment: @Felix Kling. Please put your answer so I'll mark it as correct

Comment: I've updated the answer, kindly check.

Comment: Can you put a safe  cause sometimes it says `string.replaceAll is not a function`. Some strings don't have underscores

Comment: Made changes to the logic to work with `.replace` only, kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the job :

```
function humanize(str) {
  var i, frags = str.split('_');
  for (i=0; i<frags.length; i++) {
    frags[i] = frags[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + frags[i].slice(1);
  }
  return frags.join(' ');
}


humanize('sample_orders');
// > Sample Orders
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa17mL0v/)

Comment: Thank you. Is there a cleaner and better way to do this?  using modern javascript?